# 0 records imported when using Table Data Import wizard in Mysql Workbench

Tags: mysql, csv, mysql-workbench, data-import

I am importing a CSV file to Mysql Workbench. The data have 5 fields: ID, Product, Type, Date, Revenue. The Date and Revenue fields are recorded as numbers in CSV. However, When I import the data using the Table Data Import wizard, if I select Date field Type as "Datetime", Revenue field type as "Double", I got 0 records imported. I tried to select all the fields type as "text", then I got all the records imported.

I tried to confirm the data type using Rstudio, both Date and Revenue were stored as "integer", why there are 0 records imported unless they are both classified as "text"?

I would need them to be imported as "Datetime" and "Double" for further analysis, does anyone know how to solve this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you post a small sample of the CSV file?

Comment: Hi, I copied some lines from text editor: ID,Type,Treatment Type,Date,Revenue
AC-00085,Product 1,Initial Consult,1/1/16,"2,033.27"  AC-000836,Product 1,Storage,3/1/16,90 AC-000836,Product 1,Storage,4/1/16,628.24 AC-002622,Product 1,IUI,8/1/16,"6,972.32"

Comment: Some rows in your sample data show Revenue as a string.  It is enclosed with double quotes.

Comment: Also, I think MySQL only supports ISO8601 date formats.  DATETIME may only work if the date format is yyyy-mm-dd.